# install the jquery extension for magento from the magento community

Tags: jquery, magento

I am trying to include nivo slider in magento home page for that i followed,

```
http://shakyaabiral.wordpress.com/2011/04/24/nivo-slider-in-magento-front-page/
```

I have following error

```
 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
```

Because i haven't installed jquery for magento. I dont knw how to install jquery to magento from magento community.I tried to follow this link,

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/mygento-jquery-library-and-powerful-plugins.html

I don't understand what is the use or where to include Extension key they are providing.

I also tried including jquery by

```
<action method="addJs">
<script>nivo-slider/jquery.min.js</script>
</action>
```

But it is not working..

I am using Magento 1.7

Can anyone help me with this?

Thank u

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<action method="addJs"><script>nivo-slider/jquery.min.js</script></action>
```

It is correct. 
Is your jquery.min.js file located in `/js/nivo-slider/jquery.min.js`? Please check the path.

Refresh cache from admin and refresh your current page.

If not working, take view source by right-clicking on the browser and check whether your jquery.min.js file is added and click on it to know whether file is taken. If not, you have given incorrect path to the jquery file. Please verify the path to jquery.min.js

Answer (score 1):

try this below.

```
<action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/jquery-1.6.2-no-conflict.js</name><params/></action>
<action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js</name><params/></action>
```

Comment: app/design/frontend/base/deafult/layout/page.xml . under <!--
Default layout, loads most of the pages
-->